# F2PY. Passing array. "failed in converting 2nd argument `xmin' of mga.init to C/Fortran array"

Tags: python, arrays, fortran, f2py

I am using F2PY for the first time. I have a FORTRAN routine similar to:

```
    SUBROUTINE init(ranMatr,low,upp,nbvar,size)

    IMPLICIT NONE
    INCLUDE 'parameter.h'

    DOUBLE PRECISION ranMatr(dimpop,dim), low(dim), upp(dim),sigma
    INTEGER k, j, nbvar,size

CF2PY   intent(in) low, upp, nbvar, size
CF2PY   intent(in,out) ranMatr

    DO k = 1, size
    DO j = 1, nbvar
        CALL uniforme(1,sigma)
        ranMatr(k,j) = low(j) + sigma * (upp(j) - low(j))        
    ENDDO
    ENDDO
    RETURN
    END
```

It basically initialize a random matrix called "ranMatr" with values within the range defined by low and upp. Uniforme is a routine returning a value from an uniform distribution.

Now, I installed numpy and f2py and I tried to test it with this code.

I create the python inputs as follows:

```
ranMatr = [[0 for col in range(0, 5)] for row in range(0,10)]
low = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
upp = numpy.array([6,7,8,9,10])
```

and then tried to run the routine:

```
init(ranMatr, low, upp, 5, 20)
```

But I always get this error message:

```
0-th dimension must be fixed to 100 but got 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
mga.error: failed in converting 2nd argument `low' of mga.init to C/Fortran array
```

I suppose that the problem is with dimensions but I understand that `dim` should be the upper bound for "low" vector dimensions.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `dim==100`?, I do not see a definition in the posted code.

Comment: that's because "dim" is defined in the file "parameter.h" that is included at the beginning of the fortran code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `low` array with dimension `dim` as specifies in the error message.
Some [information](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/6963) may be found here, point "2". Or you can always use `size` instead of `dim`:

```
SUBROUTINE init(ranMatr,low,upp,nbvar,size)
...
INTEGER k, j, nbvar,size
DOUBLE PRECISION ranMatr(dimpop,size), low(size), upp(size),sigma
...
```